# Why does using square brackets in subject of mailto link generate escaped spaces?

Tags: hyperref, email

When I send an email I like to include `[recipient]` in the subject so I can quickly identify responses; note the square brackets. To my knowledge, this used to work find using `href` from the `hyperref` package, but today I noticed that I get visible `%20` characters in the link preview (which I expect) and in the subject when I click to open my email client to compose the message (which I do not recall being a problem before).

Here is the MWE:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=from documentation}{someone@example.com}

Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=something from documentation}{someone@example.com}

Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=[something] from documentation}{someone@example.com}
\end{document}
```

All three show explicit escaped spaces in the link preview when I hover (I'm using TeXShop and Preview on macOS). When I click on the first two to open my email client the spaces render correctly in the subject line. However, introducing the square brackets makes `%20` appear in the subject line.

What causes this behavior and is there a simple way to make it so the square brackets do not change the behavior? I have searched this site and the `hyperref` documentation and found nothing relevant to this specific question. I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

After further experimentation, it seems that replacing `[` and `]` by `%5B` and `%5D` respectively solves the problem, but I don't entirely understand why since it's not necessary to replace the spaces with `%20`.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=from documentation}{someone@example.com}

Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=something from documentation}{someone@example.com}

Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=[something] from documentation}{someone@example.com}

Email: \href{mailto:someone@example.com?subject=%5Bsomething%5D from documentation}{someone@example.com}
\end{document}
```

Per Ulrike's comment and link this seems to be a persistent problem with Apple's PDF rendering and the solution here is at best a workaround.

Comment: There is no problem on windows with adobe reader and the url in the pdf looks ok. But preview/apple is known to mess up urls , see e.g. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/110

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was hoping Apple would have fixed this in macOS Sonoma but apparently they did not. It is very strange that certain characters seem to be problematic.